# Converting String time format of HH:MM:SS (AM/PM) into Seconds

Tags: java, string, datetime, compiler-errors

So I have this assignment that is asking us to take in a String format of time in the order of HH:MM:SSAM or HH:SS:MMPM. The constraint is that it cannot run if it is in wrong format, let it be missing any form of the AM or PM, missing a number, or if it is in 24 Hour Format.

I have the whole idea down, however for my statements, it is giving me the error of:

bad operand types for binary operator '>'
incomparable types: String and int

Did I convert them improperly or am I doing something else wrong?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Test Methods
  String fullTime1 = "03:21:36AM";
  secondsAfterMidnight(fullTime1);
}


public static int secondsAfterMidnight(String time) {
  String[] units = time.split(":");
  int hours = Integer.parseInt(units[0]);
  int minutes = Integer.parseInt(units[1]);
  int seconds = Integer.parseInt(units[2]);
  int totalSeconds = 0;
  if (units[0] > 12 || units[1] > 59 || units[2] > 59) {  //1st Error applies to these three, units[0] > 12 units[1] > 59 units[2] > 59
     return -1;
  } else if (time.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") || time.equalsIgnoreCase("PM")) {
     totalSeconds = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + (seconds);
  } else if (time.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") && units[0] == 12) { //2nd Error applies to this units[0] == 12
     totalSeconds = (minutes * 60) + (seconds);
  } else {
     return -1;
  }

  return totalSeconds;
}
```

Comment: Are you forced to doing it “by hand”? It’s much more straightforward with `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`. In production code one would no doubt use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already parsed the `String` values and saved them in the variables `hours , minutes, seconds`. Then you can use those for the check in the `if`.

Also the presence of AM?PM in the `Integer.parseInt()` will cause `NumberFormatException` to avoid it remove the String part from the number by using regex.

Also for checking the presence of `AM/PM` you can use `String.contains`.

Please check the reformatted code below:

```
public static int secondsAfterMidnight(String time) {
    String[] units = time.split(":");
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(units[0]);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(units[1]);
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(units[2].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    int totalSeconds = 0;
    if (hours > 12 || minutes > 59 || seconds > 59) {  
        return -1;
    } else if (time.contains("AM") || time.contains("PM")) {
        totalSeconds = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + (seconds);
    } else if (time.contains("AM") && hours == 12) { 
        totalSeconds = (minutes * 60) + (seconds);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
    return totalSeconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`units` is of *type* String and you are trying to compare it with an *int* hence the compile time error.

You need to convert the *String* to an *int* and then compare it, as shown below :

```
Integer.parseInt(units[0]) > 12
```

so on and so forth.

---

Also rather than re-inventing the wheel, you can make use of the already existing java-8's [**LocalTime**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) to find the number of seconds for a particular *time*:

```
public static int secondsAfterMidnight(String time) {
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a"));
    return localTime.toSecondOfDay();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that even though you have converted the `String` to `int`, you are still comparing `String` with `int`. There would also be a `RuntimeException` when you do this:

```
 int seconds = Integer.parseInt(units[2]);
```

As `units[2]` will contain `36AM`. So you should be using `substring()` to remove the "AM/PM" part.

Comment: I just got that error. Kind of confused as to where I would put the substring(). Would it be where I declared int seconds?

Comment: You could do that either at the start or where you already have `unit[2]`. eg, `Integer.parseInt(units[2].substring(0, 1));`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified your logic to calculate the seconds, but this code has corrections:

```
public static int secondsAfterMidnight(String time) {

    String[] units = time.split(":");
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(units[0]);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(units[1]);

    int seconds = 0;
    String amPm = "";

    if ( units[2].contains("AM") || units[2].contains("PM") ||
            units[2].contains("am") || units[2].contains("pm") ) {
        seconds = Integer.parseInt(units[2].substring(0, 2));
        amPm = units[2].substring(2);
    }
    else {
        seconds = Integer.parseInt(units[2]);
    }

    int totalSeconds = 0;

    if (hours > 12 || minutes > 59 || seconds > 59) {
        return -1;
    } else if (amPm.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") || amPm.equalsIgnoreCase("PM")) {
        totalSeconds = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + (seconds);
    } else if (amPm.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") && hours == 12) {
        totalSeconds = (minutes * 60) + (seconds);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

    return totalSeconds;
}
```

Comment: Please don’t solve this student’s homework for him or her. S/he learn much more from doing that himself/herself.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
static DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ssa", Locale.ENGLISH);

public static int secondsAfterMidnight(String time) {
  try {
    return LocalTime.parse(time, timeFormatter).get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY);
  } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Let’s try it out using the test code from your question:

```
  String fullTime1 = "03:21:36AM";
  System.out.println(secondsAfterMidnight(fullTime1));
```

> 12096

This is the recommended way for production code.

Only if you are doing an exercise training string manipulation, you should use one of the other answers.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.